# RecyclerView Adapter onBindViewHolder updates on second call via notifyItemChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a button in ViewHolder layout whose onClick method calls notifyItemChanged after updating some of the holder items.
onBindViewHolder gets called properly but the holder item values are not the updated ones. They get updated on second click. It's like, the onBindViewHolder is called twice in these two clicks but it has the updated values only at the second time.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PlannerRecyclerAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
    if(holder.expanded) {
        holder.toggleContentButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_less_black_24dp);
        holder.tv.setText("asdksafsaljfksafafsfa\nsasfsafasfasdsafsafsadarqr");
    } else {
        holder.toggleContentButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_24dp);
        holder.tv.setText("");
    }
    holder.toggleContentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.expanded = !holder.expanded;
            notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
}
```

This is my onBindViewHolder code.
Can someone explain why it happens so and how can I eliminate this bug to update it properly on a single click.

Comment: Instead of `holder.expanded = !holder.expanded;` use an `if esle` statement.

Comment: @MalithLakshan how would that help? if u meant to place the above if else block in onClick method, it works but without the fade animation i want using notifyItemChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the holder is recycled between the views. You should always make the layout depending on the data. In this case, you could for example create a dictionary with the position (better the id of the data object to be mapped) as key and a boolean (the "expanded" flag)as value. When you click on button, you update the corresponding flag in the dictionary.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. It works :)
Also, thanks for explaining the recycling part, justifies why I need to look more in depth henceforth

Comment: I'm really glad it solved your problem! All the best.